# Intent to play YouTube playlist

Tags: android, youtube, playlist

I would like to start YouTube playlist from my application.

For single video this is obvious

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                         Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid")));
```

but I have problem with playlist. When I put link to playlist it always plays only one video from it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are passing same url throughout the play list (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid). check for the value of videoid whether it is same.

Comment: I'm passing following link for playlist `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=first-video-id&list=playlist-id&feature=plpp_play_all` and it works in browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use YouTube functionalities in your app is to use [YouTube API for Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). You can find out how to use **YouTube API** from the documentation and the sample app.

If you use **YouTube API**, to start playlist you have to do this in your Activity:

```
String PLAYLIST_ID = "UCVHFbqXqoYvEWM1Ddxl0QDg";

//"this" is Context
Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

See the method's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents).