# Playing multiple YouTube videos in Android using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, playlist

So I'm trying to make app that will loop through a list of youtube urls. In order to play the video I am using the following code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url[i])), 0);
```

This code will loop to the next video after the user presses the back button.

Can I initiate the next video without having to click on anything? Are there any events fired off by the YouTube app that I could set a broadcast receiver to listen for?

Comment: I'm starting to realize this isn't possible. However, Is there any way to set a broadcast receiver for when the youtube app exits full screen video mode? is there also a intent that will play the youtube app in fullscreen? Because the video exiting fullscreen mode is a excellent indication of when the video has ended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play multiple YouTube videos [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) is what you have to use. This API let you play YouTube videos in your app in fullscreen or not. There is a sample app which shows how to use the library.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14953429/1726308) to know how to start a YouTube playlist.